# Numpy delete 2d index from 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have RGB image 3d array, and I want to delete specific pixel identified by there 2d position when I apply np.delete the output can not reshape to again as a 3d array, example :

```
indices = [(23, 21),(24, 22),(23, 23),(23, 24),(23, 25),(22, 26)]

I = np.empty(ImageRGB.shape())

I = np.delete(ImageRGB,obj=indices)
```

Problem : 
'I' , cannot be reshaped again due to the third color channel.

how I can delete the element in the  indices with its color channel

Comment: I don't think you can delete it. But you can change pixel's color...

Answer (score 0):

`np.delete` is intended to actually remove sections of an array, but this is probably not what you want to do when deleting pixels from an image. Instead, you probably want to set those pixels to some "background" value, which might be black (`[0, 0, 0]`) or white (likely `[1, 1, 1]` or `[255, 255, 255]`, depending how your image is encoded).

You can set those values using NumPy's indexing; for example:

```
image_rgb = np.random.rand(30, 30, 3)
indices = [(23, 21),(24, 22),(23, 23),(23, 24),(23, 25),(22, 26)]

i, j = zip(*indices)
image_rgb[i, j] = [0, 0, 0] # set values to black
```

Comment: Why did you call `zip` with `*indices` and not `indices` right away?

Comment: I want to delete a seam from the image, in the grayscale image the method is working, i delete one seam and reshape as (i-1,j) but with RGB I cannot delete the color channel.

Comment: @Swailem95 because if you don't unzip the indices it doesn't work :)

Comment: @MohamedAdel you can only do this if you are deleting an entire row or an entire column, and the indices in your example are not an entire row or column. It would help if you clarify your question.

Comment: I want to remove a seam from  RGB image, I get the seam as output from shortest path function, as an array of indices, using np.delete and reshape after work fine for grayscale image as I just delete the pixel location from the indices , but with RGB I can not delete the third dimension of the array

Answer (score 0):

I tried a solution and its working fine.
I split the image to the three color channel, after applying np.delet over every one of them and recombine them again.

Thank you every one :)